# How to merge two data frames in r by a common column with mismatched date/time values

Tags: r, merge, unique

I wish to merge two datasets using ‘date time’ columns that are present in both (POSIXct format: dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm). Below is example data from the two datasets:

```
# Dataset 1 (dts1)

           datetime   count   period   
1  30/03/2011 02:32      27      561
2  30/03/2011 02:42       3      600
3  30/03/2011 02:52       0      574
4  30/03/2011 03:02       1      550
5  30/03/2011 03:12      15      600
6  30/03/2011 03:22       0      597

# Dateset 2 (dts2)

   datetime         dist car   satd      alt
1 30/03/2011 01:59  23.9   1      3     1.76       
2 30/03/2011 02:58  14.7   1      7     6.36       
3 30/03/2011 03:55  10.4   2      9    -0.34      
4 30/03/2011 04:53  35.4   1      3     3.55      
5 30/03/2011 05:52  56.1   1      7    -0.91       
6 30/03/2011 06:48  12.3   1      4     6.58      
7 30/03/2011 07:48  10.7   1      5     4.18
```

If it was a simple case of merging matching rows from the two frames then basic `merge(data1, data2, by="datetime")` or `rbind()` function could be used.

However, my problem is more complicated as the *time intervals in the two datasets are not equal*. `Dataset 1` contains data at **precise** 10-minute intervals (each row incorporates information on the 10-minute block that ends at the specified date/time), while `dataset 2` contains data at **approximate** 1-hour intervals (each row incorporates information from the 1-hour block that ends at the specified date/time).

To make things further harder, there is a *time mismatch* between the start times of the rows in the two datasets (i.e. `dts1`: 01/03/2013 10:00:00, `dts2`: 01/03/2012 09:58:12). `dts2` intervals also vary throughout the dataset (± few minutes either side of 1 hour). I want to link every 10-minute data row in dataset 1 with the hour block that it fits within in dataset 2 (along with all the associated column values from dts2). There will be some rows that could fit into 2 different hour blocks (i.e. 30/03/2011 03:02), but I only need these rows to be linked to one of the hour blocks.

I would like to end up with something like this:

```
        datetime_dts1 count period     datetime2_dts2  dist  car satd      alt  
1    30/03/2011 02:32    27    561   30/03/2011 02:58  14.7   1     7     6.36      
2    30/03/2011 02:42     3    600   30/03/2011 02:58  14.7   1     7     6.36
3    30/03/2011 02:52     0    574   30/03/2011 02:58  14.7   1     7     6.36
4    30/03/2011 03:02     1    550   30/03/2011 02:58  14.7   1     7     6.36
5    30/03/2011 03:12    15    600   30/03/2011 03:55  10.4   2     9    -0.34
6    30/03/2011 03:22     0    597   30/03/2011 03:55  10.4   2     9    -0.34
```

I have searched for an answer to this problem but have not been able to solve it and my R abilities are not advanced. If anyone could give me a direction or provide a solution, I would be extremely grateful.

Comment: could you provide a `dput` output? it is a pain to get the data

Comment: I couldn't really follow your long text, but couldn't you just round the times and merge based on rounded times?

Comment: 5th row, `3:12` is closer to `2:58` than to `3:55`. On what basis do you assign it to `3:55`? If there are no rules, it is difficult to merge.

Comment: Hi Arun/Roland. Thanks for your comments. Arun- I assign 3:12 to 3:55 as wish for all dts1 values to be matched with the nearest hh:mm row in dts2 greater than itself, unless the value in dts1 is less than 5 minutes more than the hour:min row in dts2 proceeding it (example below). Sorry I am not sure how to provide a dput output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After first converting your datetime character strings to `POSIXt` classes, some combination of `round`ing and `trunc`ating those times should get you something you can use as the basis of a merge.

First read in your data, and create corresponding POSIXt datetimes:

```
dts1 <- structure(list(datetime = structure(1:6,
   .Label = c("30/03/2011 02:32", "30/03/2011 02:42",
   "30/03/2011 02:52", "30/03/2011 03:02", "30/03/2011 03:12",
   "30/03/2011 03:22"), class = "factor"), count = c(27L, 3L,
   0L, 1L, 15L, 0L), period = c(561L, 600L, 574L, 550L, 600L,
   597L)), .Names = c("datetime", "count", "period"),
   class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
dts2 <- structure(list(datetime = structure(1:7,
    .Label = c("30/03/2011 01:59", "30/03/2011 02:58",
    "30/03/2011 03:55", "30/03/2011 04:53", "30/03/2011 05:52",
    "30/03/2011 06:48", "30/03/2011 07:48"), class = "factor"),
    dist = c(23.9, 14.7, 10.4, 35.4, 56.1, 12.3, 10.7), car =
    c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), satd = c(3L, 7L, 9L, 3L, 7L,
    4L, 5L), alt = c(1.76, 6.36, -0.34, 3.55, -0.91, 6.58,
    4.18)), .Names = c("datetime", "dist", "car", "satd",
    "alt"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))

# create corresponding POSIXlt vector
# (you could update the 'datetime' columns in-place if you prefer)
datetime1 <- strptime(dts1$datetime, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
datetime2 <- strptime(dts2$datetime, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
```

The following code produces a merged table based on the nearest hour in all cases. Inside the merge it's just prepending a column with the rounded times to each of your data frames, merging based on that (i.e., column number 1), then using the `-1` index to remove that column at the end:

```
# merge based on nearest hour
merge(
    cbind(round(datetime1, "hours"), dts1),
    cbind(round(datetime2, "hours"), dts2),
    by=1, suffixes=c("_dts1", "_dts2")
)[-1]

     datetime_dts1 count period    datetime_dts2 dist car satd  alt
1 30/03/2011 02:32    27    561 30/03/2011 02:58 14.7   1    7 6.36
2 30/03/2011 02:42     3    600 30/03/2011 02:58 14.7   1    7 6.36
3 30/03/2011 02:52     0    574 30/03/2011 02:58 14.7   1    7 6.36
4 30/03/2011 03:02     1    550 30/03/2011 02:58 14.7   1    7 6.36
5 30/03/2011 03:12    15    600 30/03/2011 02:58 14.7   1    7 6.36
6 30/03/2011 03:22     0    597 30/03/2011 02:58 14.7   1    7 6.36
```

As above, but this time just truncating on hour:

```
merge(
    cbind(trunc(datetime1, "hours"), dts1),
    cbind(trunc(datetime2, "hours"), dts2),
    by=1, suffixes=c("_dts1", "_dts2")
)[-1]

     datetime_dts1 count period    datetime_dts2 dist car satd   alt
1 30/03/2011 02:32    27    561 30/03/2011 02:58 14.7   1    7  6.36
2 30/03/2011 02:42     3    600 30/03/2011 02:58 14.7   1    7  6.36
3 30/03/2011 02:52     0    574 30/03/2011 02:58 14.7   1    7  6.36
4 30/03/2011 03:02     1    550 30/03/2011 03:55 10.4   2    9 -0.34
5 30/03/2011 03:12    15    600 30/03/2011 03:55 10.4   2    9 -0.34
6 30/03/2011 03:22     0    597 30/03/2011 03:55 10.4   2    9 -0.34
```

As above, but for dts1 treat the record as belonging to previous hour until 10 minutes past the hour, by subtracting 10*60 seconds before truncating. This one produces the same output you specified, though without more information I'm not sure that it's the exact rule you want.

```
merge(
    cbind(trunc(datetime1 - 10*60, "hours"), dts1),
    cbind(trunc(datetime2, "hours"), dts2),
    by=1, suffixes=c("_dts1", "_dts2")
)[-1]

     datetime_dts1 count period    datetime_dts2 dist car satd   alt
1 30/03/2011 02:32    27    561 30/03/2011 02:58 14.7   1    7  6.36
2 30/03/2011 02:42     3    600 30/03/2011 02:58 14.7   1    7  6.36
3 30/03/2011 02:52     0    574 30/03/2011 02:58 14.7   1    7  6.36
4 30/03/2011 03:02     1    550 30/03/2011 02:58 14.7   1    7  6.36
5 30/03/2011 03:12    15    600 30/03/2011 03:55 10.4   2    9 -0.34
6 30/03/2011 03:22     0    597 30/03/2011 03:55 10.4   2    9 -0.34
```

You could tweak the details of which ones you round, which ones you truncate, and whether you first subtract/add some time depending on your specific rule.

**Edit:**

Not the most elegant, but here is a different approach that accommodates the more complicated conditional rule you described in your comments. This leans heavily on `na.locf` from the zoo package to first determine which dts2 times come before and after each dts1 record. With those in hand, it's just a matter of applying the rule to select the desired dts2 time, matching back to the original dts1 table, then merging.

```
library(zoo)

# create ordered list of all datetimes, using names to keep
# track of which ones come from each data frame
alldts <- sort(c(
    setNames(datetime1, rep("dts1", length(datetime1))),
    setNames(datetime2, rep("dts2", length(datetime2)))))
is.dts1 <- names(alldts)=="dts1"

# for each dts1 record, get previous closest dts2 time
dts2.prev <- alldts
dts2.prev[is.dts1] <- NA
dts2.prev <- na.locf(dts2.prev, na.rm=FALSE)[is.dts1]

# for each dts1 record, get next closest dts2 time
dts2.next <- alldts
dts2.next[is.dts1] <- NA
dts2.next <- na.locf(dts2.next, na.rm=FALSE, fromLast=TRUE)[is.dts1]

# for each dts1 record, apply rule to choose dts2 time
use.prev <- !is.na(dts2.prev) & (alldts[is.dts1] - dts2.prev < 5)
dts2.to.use <- ifelse(use.prev, as.character(dts2.prev), 
    as.character(dts2.next))

# merge based on chosen dts2 times, prepended as character vector
# for the purpose of merging
merge(
    cbind(.dt=dts2.to.use[match(datetime1, alldts[is.dts1])], dts1),
    cbind(.dt=as.character(datetime2), dts2),
    by=".dt", all.x=TRUE, suffixes=c("_dts1", "_dts2")
)[-1]
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions regetz. Very helpful. The problem with subtracting 10*60 before truncating is that it only considers the hour, not the minutes. My hour values in dts2 are not always 60 minutes long. Instead, I want the script to look at each row in dts1 and match it to the nearest hour:min row in dts2 that is greater than itself, unless the value in dts1 is less than 5 minutes more than the hour:min row in dts2 proceeding it.

Comment: An Example: `30/03/2011 03:32` matched to `30/03/2011 03:49`, `30/03/2011 03:42` matched to `30/03/2011 03:49`, **`30/03/2011 03:52` matched to `30/03/2011 03:49`**, `30/03/2011 04:02` matched to `30/03/2011 04:42` and so on....

Comment: Excellent, this is exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks for your extensive answer. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The selector of data.table seems well suited for that. It is really efficient and allow to merge the nearest value (upper or lower or both).

Find on this website: https://www.r-bloggers.com/understanding-data-table-rolling-joins/ example for left, right joins...etc

```
website[, join_time:=session_start_time]
paypal[, join_time:=purchase_time]
setkey(website, name, join_time)
setkey(paypal, name, join_time)
website[paypal, roll = T]
```

About DT: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html